# Numerators in LoopTools

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, computational-physics, feynman-diagrams, software

I want to calculate the diagram
$$ \int \text{d}^D q \frac{q_\mu q_\nu q_\rho q_\eta}{(q^2-m_1^2)((q_1+p_1)^2-m_2^2)((q_1+p_1+p_2)^2-m_3^2)((q_1+p_1+p_2+p_3)^2-m_4^2)((q_1+p_1+p_2+p_3+p_4)^2-m_5^2)} $$

with [LoopTools](https://feynarts.de/looptools/). I do not understand which tensor coefficient from LoopTools is required here, since all the tensor coefficients only have combinations of $p$ momenta and not $q$.

Comment: This seems to be highly specific to whatever LoopTools is, have you looked into their user forums or support team?

Comment: Sadly they do not have a user forum or support team that I am aware of. Their definition of coefficients can be found on page 8 in the manual: https://feynarts.de/looptools/LT215Guide.pdf , but I don't know how to get from there to my problem.